# Why this ajax request is successful when request method is GET but fails in POST method

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

When I set the request type to "GET",(and also use $_GET on server side), it successfully fetches the response, 
but gives a `400 error`, `Missing required parameters: student_id` when I set the type to POST.

Here's the code :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "?r=fees/fees/transactions",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { student_id: student_id },           
        success:function( msg ) { 
            console.log(msg);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            console.log("failed");
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(ajaxOptions);
            console.log(thrownError);    
        }
});
```

Here is the request URL when I set the request method to GET:

`http://localhost/demo.git/index.php?r=fees/fees/transactions&_csrf=bEJJWVowdl8jBwQjaUMsAA52eT8MXBMLJigwHTxeKSlVKyxoD2o5KQ%3D%3D&student_id=10115"`.

why doesn't this work when I set the above request type to POST and receive the variable on server side by POST method?

Here is the server side action (I am using Yii2 MVC framework)

```
public function actionTransactions($student_id){
    $student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
        ...
        ...   
    echo json_encode($response);

}
```

Comment: downvoter, care to comment ?

Comment: How can you get $_GET method parameters in $_POST ??

Comment: You Can use $_REQUEST if you dont know the method is $_GET or $_POST

Comment: @YasinPatel, that does not relates at all to what I asked?  Did I say that I don't know the method?  I am working on localhost you see. I know by which method I am calling.

Comment: Its not fare, why are you give down vote. I solved  your problem.

Comment: Mat hata chutiye mujhe koi fark nhi padta me to bas help karta hu logo ki kuch tujh jaise bhi milte hai or aage bhi milenge or downvote kar de mere baap ka kya jaa rha. HAHAHA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function need param `$student_id` from `GET` method. If youre using AJAX to send request, using `data: { 'student_id': student_id },` - it will be added to your URL where AJAX is sent.

If you want to use `POST` method, you have to modify your URL:

```
url: "?r=fees/fees/transactions?student_id=" + student_id,
```

And remove `data` key.

Second solution is to remove `$student_id` param from your `actionTransactions`, then system will accept requests without `$student_id` in `GET`, but you will have to ensure, that it's in `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: Though the answer was a bit late, as I already figured it out, this is definitely a complete solution. Also, don't you think the question deserves an upvote? If you do please upvote, because personally I think that I made every effort to  clearly and completely describe the problem which can be reproduced. and documentation about this is also not so common, at least I could not find.